# Can someone help me find a sans-serif font with points over uppercase "i" ("I")?

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, sans-serif

The "I" character in that font should have a circle/disc/bullet above it, just like "i". I need this font to use it as the default font for my Blogger blog posts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by simply looking at fonts.

Comment: I searched for such a font on Google and I did not find it. There are so many fonts on the Internet that looking at fonts can be a huge and hard task. I expected a link to a font from the answerers. From this point of view, I request that you remove your negative vote.

Answer (score 7):

Most current fonts should have one. In Western European typography there is no dot on the upper case "I", but in Turkish, [there are dotted and dotless "i"/"ı" whose uppercase versions are dotted and dottless "İ"/"I"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) that you should see here because your browser fonts likely support them.

So it's not a matter of finding a font, but of using the adequate character codes...

Answer (score 0):

silviubogan is talking about this character, İ,  [that is used in a few alphabets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) and is trying to find a sans-serif version.  I don't know why someone voted his question down. Probably because they didn't carefully read the question and notice he was talking about UPPERCASE i not standard lowercase i. I voted it up but since I'm new my vote doesn't display yet. Sad face.

silviubogan, I assume you are Romanian, but it seems this character is only used in Turkish and a few related languages that derive from Turkish. So you just need to find a good sans-serif font that includes the characters from the extended Latin alphabet.